# Unable to use google-cloud in a GAE app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

The following line in my Google App Engine app (`webapp.py`) fails to import the [Google Cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) library:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

With the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.storage
```

I did some research and found the following articles to be helpful:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34585485
- https://www.simonmweber.com/2013/06/18/python-protobuf-on-app-engine.html

Using a combination of the techniques suggested by the above articles, I did the following:

1. Create a `requirements.txt` file:

   ```
   google-cloud==0.19.0
   ```
2. Import this library using `pip`:

   ```
   pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
   ```
3. Use the following code in my `appengine_config.py` file:

   ```
   import os
   import sys
   import google
   libDir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib")
   google.__path__.append(os.path.join(libDir, "google"))
   sys.path.insert(0, libDir)
   ```

Can anyone shed light on what I might be missing to get this working? I'm just trying to write a Google App Engine app that can write/read from Google Cloud Storage, and I'd like to test locally before deploying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [App Engine specific Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) that ships with the App Engine SDK that you can use to work with Cloud Storage buckets.

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
```

Is there a reason you didn't use this built-in library, which requires no configuration to load?

Comment: I tried that after atimothee's 2nd suggestion and it worked! It wasn't clear to me that I should be using one over the other.

Comment: The fact that there are two libraries is rather confusing. Trying to search for one of them while excluding the other is pretty hard, but afaik `cloudstorage` does not support resumable uploads, while `google.cloud.storage` does.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the only thing that is required is to include `google-cloud` into your project `requirements.txt` file.

Check if this simple sample works for you (you shouldn't get any imports error). 
Create below files and run `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`. Nothing more is required on my site to make it work.

**app.yaml**

```
application: mysample
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: main.app
```

**main.py**

```
import webapp2
from google.cloud import storage


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

**appengine_config.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
import os

# Third-party libraries are stored in "lib", vendoring will make
# sure that they are importable by the application.
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'lib')):
    vendor.add('lib')
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-cloud
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion in a test project, but got the same error: `ImportError: No module named google.cloud.storage`

Comment: are you starting dev server by running `dev_appserver.py` or `GoogleAppEngineLauncher` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your appengine_config.py only needs to contain:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

All the rest you have posted looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, dyeray! I tried replacing the contents of the `appengine_config.py` file with that and I'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't know where the problem is then. It works for me by using above code with a fairly standard project with the latest version of Google Cloud SDK and deploying with *gcloud app deploy --project=<my-project-name>*. Maybe there is something else going on in your project?

Comment: Oh! I'm attempting to run my app locally using `dev_appserver.py`. Does that work for you on your project?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your message. I tried my code locally, but I hit yet another bug on the loval dev environment: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/578. I don't think these guys are doing a good job at keeping the new generation libraries compatible with the local devserver. Maybe using the Google API Client libraries is an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The package namespace seems to have been changed as pointed out in this [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/2264) and hasn't been fully fixed. You could install the older version (`pip install gcloud`) which uses a different namespace & use this import statement instead:

```
from gcloud import storage
```

You should also ensure that you're importing vendor libs in your appengine_config.py as pointed out in dyeray's answer.

The issue seems to have been fixed as at version 0.20.0 of google-cloud. So the import statement in the question should work. Just remember to run `pip install --upgrade google-cloud`

Comment: If you're only interested in Cloud storage on appengine, you could just use the appengine Google cloud storage client lib https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage

Comment: The above import statement didn't work, either. Now I'm getting: `ImportError: No module named gcloud`

Comment: Looks like the Google Cloud Storage Client Library ended up working for me—thanks, atimothee!

Answer (score 0):

you should move "import google" line to the position after sys.path.insert

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem and took a long time to sort it out.

**Setup 1**:
If your `app.yaml` is set up like below:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15
```

And your `main.py` is registered your script as an app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello World!'
```

You should be able to run just fine on the google cloud.

**Setup 2**: How I ran into the `ImportModule error` -
In my `app.yaml` file I replaced `script=main.app` with `script=main.app` and deleted the

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

from `main.py file`. As a result, `appengine_config.py` isn't getting run for setting the sys path. The solution is that you can either follow the pattern like Setup 1 or add the followings to your `main.py` file.

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

Then the app should have the right path for importing the third-party packages. Hope it helps.