# The worker for a Google Cloud Platform task cannot find the logging library

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have created a simple task based on the Google Cloud Platform ["update counter" push task example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/taskqueue/counter). All I want to do is log that it has been invoked to the Stackdriver logs.

```
from google.cloud import logging
logging_client = logging.Client()
log_name = 'service-log'
logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)

import webapp2

class UpdateCounterHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        amount = int(self.request.get('amount'))
        logger.log_text('Service startup task done.')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/update_counter', UpdateCounterHandler)
], debug=True)
```

After deploying this and invoking it, there is an error. In the logs online it says:

```
from google.cloud import logging
ImportError: No module named cloud
```

This isn't a local version, but one that I've deployed. It's hard for me to believe that I have to actually install python libraries into the production runtime. (I can't even imagine that I can.)

Answer (score 1):

As the [root readme](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard#user-content-deploying-the-samples) states:

> Many samples require extra libraries to be installed. If there is a `requirements.txt`, you will need to install the dependencies with `pip`.

Try adding the library as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39815014/3615567).

Answer (score 0):

When using `logging` from the Python standard library in App Engine, the logs also end up in Stackdriver. So you could use `import logging` instead of `from google.cloud import logging`.

When you are specifically interested in using the `google.cloud.logging` library, then it needs to be installed to a project folder `./lib` as referred by Tudormi:  [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)